# Configuring a Fody solution weaver

Tags: .net, configuration, aop, fody

I am using [Fody in-solution weaving](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/wiki/InSolutionWeaving). I have a couple of projects configured to use Fody and would like them to be able to pass in configuration to my weaver in the same fashion any other weaver could (via an auto-wired `Config` property). However, I am unable to find any documentation on how to achieve this.

Is it supported? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

u should be able to reference the reference the solution weaver by name. as is done here https://github.com/Fody/Fody/blob/master/Integration/WithNugetAndInSolutionWeavers/FodyWeavers.xml

then you can pass configuration to it